# variable 'QGraphicsView v' has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, qt4

Здравствуйте, такая проблема:

```
/home/u0807/QtApplication_2/main.cpp:182: ошибка: variable 'QGraphicsView     
v' has initializer but incomplete type QGraphicsView v(&m);
                ^
```

```
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    myClass m;
    QGraphicsView v(&m);
    v.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    v.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    v.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    v.show();
    v.setGeometry(1320, 610, 23, 125);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В начало допишите:

```
#include <QGraphicsView>
```

## Объяснение

В Qt где только возможно применяются forward-declarations. Это позволяет ускорить компиляцию, так как сокращает количество обрабатываемых `#include`.

Данная ошибка как раз и возникает, когда у компилятора есть только forward-declaration, а в этом месте нужно уже полное определение.